# views outside the controller in custom module drupal 8?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, drupal, module, drupal-8

Hi all I am also new to `drupal 8`, however I am finding it interesting, I have been with `zend framework, symfony, yii or .NET MVC`

but i want to ask, is there no way of building your views outside the controller of your custom module?

if there is can anyone point me to the right direction.

Something that can make me have my controller totally separated from the way i can render my views on the page just like the `chtml` in `.NET` or `.phtml` in the `Zend framework` of `magento`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is returning either a Symfony Response object or a [Drupal render array](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x). In the case of the render array you want to be returning structured data not HTML markup. The actual rendering of the array into markup either happens within a theme function provided by Drupal Core or a module (your own included) which use Twig to actually generate the markup.

You may find the [overview of the Render Pipline](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/render/pipeline) useful.